# I'm trying to delete call log like +911111 but it is not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to delete call log such as +911111, but it's not working. The following code is working on 11111 type numbers, but it is not working on numbers like +911111 this. It is deleting only 11111 type numbers.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String number = "11111";
    String queryString="NUMBER="+number; 
        int del = this.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,queryString,null);

        if(del == 1)
          Log.d("Delete", "Delete Number" + queryString);
        else
          Log.d("Not Delete", "Not Delete" + queryString);
  }
```

Comment: I've assumed java and android - but shouldn't have had to. If these are wrong, please re-edit your question and add *appropriate* language tag(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the single quotes around the number.Replace the queryString with below code:

```
String queryString = "NUMBER LIKE '" + number + "'";
```

Like:

```
String number = "+911111";
getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,queryString,  
null)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not delete number like +911111 because your queryString says "="

Try to change it to

```
String queryString="NUMBER LIKE "+number;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This would still have the same effect, wrap `number` in %-s.

Comment: Hi @Mystic I tried "NUMBER LIKE"+number But it is not working. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @user3114599 Change it to `String queryString = "NUMBER LIKE '%" + number + "%'";`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the contract class provided by the SDK ( CallLog.Calls in your situation ) when building your queries.

The contract classes are meant to map the object model to the corresponding data names in the database. When the android team need to update a column name in the database, they also update the contract class and then no change is required for developpers.

Then try to change you query string to :

```
String queryString = CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + "='" + strNumber + "'";
```

NOTE: the single-quote marks are necessary.

Also make sure the number is exactly matching the database number

```
( +33678541236 != 0678541236 )
```

To be sure to delete the correct row you can do the following :

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ? ", strNumber , "");
int idOfRowToDelete = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(idOfRowToDelete)), "", null);
```

Comment: the following code giving such error "android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1"